# Hachoir Python Implementation on Blackberry

Tags: python, blackberry, android-ndk, java, hachoir-parser

I need to implement the Hachoir libraries to parse through image files (the meta-data in them). My project requires this to be done on a Blackberry device, hence that would mean I will have to port the entire Hachoir library to Blackberry.

The other thing I could do is to, write python scripts (which utilizes the Hachoir libraries) and find a way to call these scripts from the Blackberry. I read that it is possible to call python scripts using NDK on Android. Is there a similar tool for Blackberry?

So in the end I will have to install hachoir(??) on the phone, call the scripts through the "NDK equivalent tool", capture the output again through this tool and display it to the user.

Any suggestions on the tools to be used and the method in general? Are there any other suggestions for hachoir like libraries on Java? Thanks!

Comment: There is no NDK equivalent on BlackBerry OS. There is on BlackBerry Tablet OS. So if you wrote your solution for the PlayBook using the NDK it would work on BlackBerry 10 devices when they come out. There is this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168472/media-information-extractor-for-java which seems more aimed at video but might help.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I have been looking at Jython and it looks like a good option for running Python scripts from Java. Jython also runs on any platform which supports a JVM, however I am not sure if I would be able to use Jython on Blackberry?
Does the Blackberry platform support a JVM?

Comment: Can someone please suggest how can I make python scripts run on Blackberry OS?

Comment: BlackBerry OS supports J2ME with extensions. The JVM is non-standard (RIM has implemented their own JVM with different byte codes than standards). This means that you will have to compile any Java you want to use with RIM tools. Sometimes you can link with a JAR but it depends on the dependencies of the JAR and what version of Java compiled it.

Answer (score 0):

Peter Hansen has Python running native on the BB playbook. See [this link](http://peterhansen.ca/blog/bbx-python-self-contained-demo-app.html).

Comment: For what it's worth, we've gone well beyond what was mentioned in that early post. We've ported PySide, so now you can write full Qt apps in Python (including using QML, which rocks) for the PlayBook and BB10 devices.  See http://blackberry-py.microcode.ca/ and follow @BBPyProject on twitter.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can write your own script using the python app, and then port it (if needed) to peter's framework (which is very cool too)
http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/32880889/