# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'mediainfo': The specified module could not be found

Tags: java, video, java-native-interface, metadata, mediainfo

I am using the **MediaInfo.java** class which can be found on [sub4me](http://code.google.com/p/subs4me/source/browse/trunk/Subs4me/src/net/sourceforge/filebot/mediainfo/?r=93)  to extract meta data from various video file formats. However I get the above error at run time.

This is an extract of my code, the exception is thrown at `MediaInfo info = new MediaInfo()`

```
String fileName = "file:///homes/sa303/NetBeansProjects/MoviePlayer1/src/Trailer/IronMan3.mp4";
File file1 = new File(fileName);
System.out.println(file1.getPath());

MediaInfo info = new MediaInfo();
info.open(file1);

String format = info.get(MediaInfo2.StreamKind.Video, 1, "Format", MediaInfo2.InfoKind.Text, MediaInfo2.InfoKind.Name);
String bitRate = info.get(MediaInfo2.StreamKind.Video, 1, "BitRate", MediaInfo2.InfoKind.Text, MediaInfo2.InfoKind.Name);
String frameRate = info.get(MediaInfo2.StreamKind.Video, 1, "FrameRate", MediaInfo2.InfoKind.Text, MediaInfo2.InfoKind.Name);
String width = info.get(MediaInfo2.StreamKind.Video, 1, "Width", MediaInfo2.InfoKind.Text, MediaInfo2.InfoKind.Name);

String audioBitrate = info.get(MediaInfo2.StreamKind.Audio, 1, "BitRate", MediaInfo2.InfoKind.Text, MediaInfo2.InfoKind.Name);
String audioChannels = info.get(MediaInfo2.StreamKind.Audio, 1, "Channels", MediaInfo2.InfoKind.Text, MediaInfo2.InfoKind.Name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7114893/600132) answer, the class `MediaInfo` is just JNI wrapper, so you need to download [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/) distribution to according platform and add those native library files to class path of your project..