# Some url is not working in online radio android

Tags: java, android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

for Streaming radio online code is below

```
   player = new MediaPlayer();
   player.setDataSource(RADIO_STATION_URL);
   player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            player.start();
        }
    });
```

if i put url in place of RADIO_STATION_URL like http://test1.leanstream-hd.com/CFHKFM, it will give me an error

```
    02-18 17:12:34.035: E/MediaPlayer(1205): error (1, -2147483648)
```

and player is not working it will work on many url but in this case of url it is not working :(

I have googled and i got that some media format is not supported by mediaplayer by below link

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

but can anybody suggest me how to find that **Which url is containing which media format** I want to make UNIVERSAL RADIO application in that link come from server which is dynamic

Comment: Once check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7114893/1398150) it may usefull

Answer (score 2):

Run the URI in the vlc and go to `Tool --> Codec Information` to check the detail.. Following are the screen shot for the http://test1.leanstream-hd.com/CFHKFM URI

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you sooooo much :) Praful Bhatnagar

Comment: Can you try http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener.html and check for http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#MEDIA_INFO_METADATA_UPDATE event,,

Comment: Praful just last one if the file contain ACC file than have u solution or example for streaming that file? i have checked http://code.google.com/p/opencore-aacdec/ that library is used for streaming ACC file but i do not know how to use that library because it contain only .c and .h file i think NDK will be required but can u have an exmaple that uses this code than please tell me

Comment: you can read this http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html to uderstand how ndk works.. sorry I don't have the sample code.. also as per official doc found here http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html it should be supported out of the box..